# People of public interest living in Germany

Tags: data-request, germany

I am interested in a list of people of public interest living in Germany. The list should contain first name, last name, date of birth.
People of public interest are celebrities, famous sportman/ -women, known politicians, etc.
In wikipedia I can find many but, I have to search and record manually. Is there a structured list or / API which enables that ?

Comment: Welcome to Open Data SE! Just to clarify: Are you really interested in their place of residency or more in their citizenship? Two quick examples: Are you interested in John B. Emerson, the US Ambassador to Germany? Also, are you interested in Franka Potente, who currently lives in Los Angeles?

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for the quick comment! I am interested in people living in Germany - so John Emerson should be in the result set. However, I do not expect to get a 'complete' list - I have not been too specific about the definition of popis. Also containing some false positives (Germans living abroad) is not desired but I can deal with it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Another quick question: How do you currently search in Wikipedia for people who live in Germany?

Comment: I don't know of a systematic way. If I read a wikipedia article though, you may find the information where he lives. E.g. if you look at the wiki page of Boris Becker.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Germans can get you started, although it is many dead and/or infamous people, too. Interestingly, no German language version of that page exists.

Comment: p.s. I think John Emerson, the US Ambassador to Germany, is a tough example. Those positions are temporary and technically he's a US government employee.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Germans is not ideal because it neither restricts to *living people* nor to people *living in Germany*. However I completely agree that John Emerson is a tough example ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [category called "Deutscher" (German) in the German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kategorie:Deutscher) that is accessible [with the help of the German DBpedia](http://de.dbpedia.org/page/Kategorie:Deutscher) and contains more than 191000 pages. You could query DBpedia for pages that have a link to this category with the [wikiPageWikiLink](http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageWikiLink) relation and filter for living people by looking up if their DBpedia page contains a death date or not, using [deathDate](http://dbpedia.org/ontology/deathDate).

Answer (score 2):

We found that next to DBpedia there is a commercial site https://www.munzinger.de/ which contains all the data relevant to the question free on their web site and have it accessible.

Comment: How is that data free or accessible? You would have to scrape it from their website and I haven't found any licence information.